# Live reload is not working with Ionic serve command

Tags: ionic-framework, livereload

As per the Ionic Guide Chapter 4 http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html, ionic serve will start a live reload server, which it does in my case, but reload is not happening.

Is there any pre-req we need to have for this thing to work? Like say live reload chrome extension?

```
E:\Ionic\myapp>ionic serve
Running dev server: http://localhost:8100
Running live reload server: http://localhost:35729
```

Comment: check if its injecting a script into your page,should be something like <script src="http://192.168.0.1:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></script>. If there is a script it shouldn't need the extension, and all should be working fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

- stop ionic service if you running it 'q' command
- run: `ionic address` from command prompt

After running this command it will prompt you to select what address you would like to use one is localhost and the second one is your machine IP address.
Try to use select your machine IP address instead of localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Even I faced similar issue, console used to display the file changed but automatic browser refresh wasn't happening. Later I found out a missing closing tag in my index.html page that prevented ionic to inject the below script required for live reload.

```
    <script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></script>
```

Please check for any typo errors or other html issues in the index.html page and fix those. Live reload should word properly after that.

Answer (score 2):

In Ionic 2/3, I solved this problem by removing the folder `node_modules/` and file `package-lock.json`, then at terminal run:
`npm install --save`

Answer (score 0):

I'm my case, I was bootstraping the app with this:

```
window.ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
 angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

Then I changed it for this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" >
   <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

And it works

Answer (score 0):

> if you want to get Live console logs in the ionic application (real
> device or emulator)

```
ionic cordova run android --livereload  --consolelogs --serverlogs
```