# Unable to update livereload IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to IONIC. I have successfully installed ionic and cordova. But when I am editing html template it is showing me this error. I am behind a corporate proxy.

[image]

edit 1
[image]

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392507/live-reload-is-not-working-with-ionic-serve-command

Comment: Sorry I tried as per your suggestion but didn't get success.

Comment: Can you try typing `ionic address` into terminal and choosing local host as the address that Ionic will be serving and then try again.

Comment: @thepio yes I have tried but still the same issue I am facing. Is this a problem due to proxy ?

Comment: @Antonis I have edited my question. plz have a look.

Comment: So did you have a server running on the same port probably?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328184/ionic-serve-displays-multiple-addresses-and-i-chose-wrong-one-how-to-change-ad